# Nginx does not serve static files over HTTPS

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy

I am trying to set up Nginx in front of Apache as a reverse proxy and to serve static files. I 301 http to https, and provide the directives in https section to serve a static folder via an alias. However, for some strange reason the files get served via http.

Here's my Nginx site config:

```
    server {
            listen   80; 
            listen   [::]:80;
            access_log off;
            server_name site.com www.site.com;
            return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

        }

    server {
            listen   443;
            ssl on;

            ssl_certificate /usr/local/sslcert/my.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/sslcert/my.key;

            access_log off;
            server_name site.com www.site.com;


            location /public/ {
            alias /var/www/public/;
            expires max;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            }


            location / {

            root /var/www/;
            index index.php

            client_max_body_size    10m;
            client_body_buffer_size 128k;

            proxy_send_timeout   90;
            proxy_read_timeout   90;
            proxy_buffer_size    128k;
            proxy_buffers     4 256k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
            proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
            proxy_connect_timeout 30s;

            proxy_redirect  off;

            proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:3333/;

            proxy_set_header   Host   $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            }



            location /push {
            root /var/www/;
            rewrite /push(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8332/push/;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            }

             location ~ /\.ht {
                    deny all;
            }
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: site.com just redirected me to salesforce.com. What is going on here? Isn't that your site?

Comment: no, I have changed it for privacy purposes

Comment: [You may need to provide the actual name](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632) in order for anyone to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was actually with Zend Framework BaseUrl setting. I have removed it, and everything is working now.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the actual reason for the problem, but it causes difficulties anyway.

You are using `root` inside location blocks, which doesn't work out nicely in general.

Try this configuration:

```
server {
        listen   80; 
        listen   [::]:80;
        access_log off;
        server_name site.com www.site.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /usr/local/sslcert/my.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/sslcert/my.key;

        access_log off;
        server_name site.com www.site.com;

        root /var/www;

        location /public/ {
            expires max;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }

        location / {
            index index.php

            client_max_body_size    10m;
            client_body_buffer_size 128k;

            proxy_send_timeout   90;
            proxy_read_timeout   90;
            proxy_buffer_size    128k;
            proxy_buffers     4 256k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
            proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
            proxy_connect_timeout 30s;

            proxy_redirect  off;

            proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:3333/;

            proxy_set_header   Host   $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        location /push {
            rewrite ^/push(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8332/push/;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

         location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Changes:

- Moved ssl definition to the listen line
- Added IPv6 to SSL section
- Moved `root` directive to server level
- Removed unneeded `alias` and `root` definitions from location blocks, the server level `root` directive covers these
- Added start of line `^` to the push `rewrite` rule.

Comment: thanks for the feedback! unfortunately that does not solve the issue :(